# Excel Formula > Selecting specific date of next month

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I am trying to set up an automatic cell in Excel to show the same day of the Next Month based on the current month.

In other words, if today is 11/20/2020, and I want to show the 13th day of the Next month, I'd want the cell to end up showing 12/13/2020.

I know that EDATE can help me calculate 1 month into the future based on a start date, but I dont want to have to change the start date on my spreadsheet every month.

To give a little background, this is basically a spreadsheet for paying bills. Some bills are due on the day day each month. I'd like to auto calculate the actual due date, and then use conditional formatting to highlight which bills are due within the next 14 days. I think I have the conditional formatting piece ready, I just dont know how to calculate the dates as I laid out above.

Comment: So if today was 11/19/2020, what would you want to show next month? Still 12/13 or would it be 12/12? In other words, are you trying add a certain number of days to something?

Comment: Trying to always show the 13th of the month, as long as it's next month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GOAL:**  Display the date of the 13<sup>th</sup> of the month after the month given by the `TODAY()` function.

How about:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,13)
```

[image]

Note:  the formula will correctly roll forward from December to January of the next year.

Comment: Thanks! this is perfect

Comment: @TomD You are quite welcome!